# Laravel 6.2.0, one-to-one models saved except for the foreign key

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have a one-to-one relationship model, and I'm trying to save the data into my database. Upon saving, it does not save the foreign id of its *hasOne* class (Workday). It is a vacancy post, tied with a workdays

```
Schema::create('vacancies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    // other data
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('workdays_id')->index();
    // other data
});

Schema::create('workdays', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('vacancy_id')->index();
    $table->boolean('monday')->nullable();
    .
    .
    .
    $table->boolean('sunday')->nullable();
});
```

Models

```
class Vacancy extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        // other data
        // does not have workdays_id & it's own id column
    ];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }

    public function workday()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Workday::class);
    }
}

class Workday extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'monday',
        'tuesday',
        'wednesday',
        'thursday',
        'friday',
        'saturday',
        'sunday'
    ];

    public function vacancy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vacancy::class);
    }
}
```

In my VacancyController, I've taken the inputs and created the Vacancy and make the Workday

```
$workdayInputs = $request->workdays;

$vacancy = Vacancy::create($inputs);
$workday = new Workday;

$workday->monday = in_array('monday', $workdayInputs);
$workday->tuesday = in_array('tuesday', $workdayInputs);
$workday->wednesday = in_array('wednesday', $workdayInputs);
$workday->thursday = in_array('thursday', $workdayInputs);
$workday->friday = in_array('friday', $workdayInputs);
$workday->saturday = in_array('saturday', $workdayInputs);
$workday->sunday = in_array('sunday', $workdayInputs);


$workday->vacancy()->associate($vacancy);
$workday->save();

$vacancy->workday()->save($workday);
```

The statement
**$workday->vacancy()->associate($vacancy); $workday->save()** did save the vacancy's id, but

**$vacancy->workday()->save($workday)** did not

Comment: Typically in a one to one relationship the foreign key only exists on the model that that "belongsTo" the other, can you describe the relationship a little more?

Comment: So a vacancy is like a job post and has their working days. Some company starts working from Monday until Friday, others on Monday until Thursday & Saturday etc. I want to populate the column days to a separate table because it doesn't look nice in the vacancy table. A vacancy is a parent, the workday is the children and its a one-to-one relationship. But from I understand from your comment, the vacancy wouldn't need a foreign key, only the workday, right?